# «Амбар и палата»

Tags: лексика, выбор-слов, история

В только что [закончившейся](https://olymp.hse.ru/data/2017/11/21/1160779975/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%201%20%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B0%20(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82).pdf) олимиаде по русскому языку «Высшая проба» было такое задание:

> Это слово в современном русском языке — существительное женского рода, а когда-то оно было прилагательным и употреблялось как определение к словам «амбар» и «палата». Что это за слово?

Когда мне показали это задание, никаких здравых мыслей на его счет у меня не возникло. Может быть, вместе мы придем к правильному ответу?

Comment: Пробирка? К амбару с некоторой натяжкой можно привязать: амбары (как склады) были наряду с пробирной конторой (более величально - палатой). в имуществе злато-серебро-обрабатывающих предприятий. http://ez.chita.ru/encycl/person/?id=476

Comment: @Alex_ander версия интересная, однако навряд ли это должен знать школьник...

Comment: Я бы искал в ответе существительное, которое относится к типу полной субстантивации. Лушчий вариант, который я могу придумать, — "кладовая". К некоторым пунктам он хорошо подходит, но к другим — с натяжкой (или у меня не хватает эрудиции).

Comment: @grizzly посовещавшись с одним человеком, я пришёл именно к такому ответу. Но правилен ли он, точно не известно.

Comment: Спасибо! Было интересно :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Предлагаю вариант "**Кладовая**".

Преимущества этого варианта: относится к типу полной субстантивации (было прилагательным, в современном языке — только существительное женского рода); очевидная связь с определением амбара. Не могу уверенно говорить о связи со старым определением палаты, но поиск в сети много раз находит сочетание "кладовая палата" в старинных текстах.

Comment: Кладовая палата — скорее всего, от Клада = колода, колодка, цепи, тюрьма — следственный изолятор.

Comment: Т. е. всё-таки вопрос в задании был сформулирован двусмысленно: противопоставление "существительного" "определению" многих заставляет искать прилагательное, сочетаемое с каждым из двух слов, а на самом деле речь шла о "даче определения" двум словам? Но и тогда не сходится: амбар - кладовая; сочетания "кладовой амбар" нет, а палате нужно определение.

Comment: @Alex_ander Я предположил, что оба слова определялись через "кладовую". При этом в словаре Даля мы находим, например, в статье "палата" среди прочего: "особое место склада, амбар". Какая-то связь была, но точно я не могу сказать.

Comment: Это понятно, но палата не определяется через кладовую: кладовая палата - частный случай палаты (можно только добавить прилагательное, которое бывает "определением" в качестве члена предложения, но не является _определением понятия,_ как в случае амбара). Здесь смешение двух разных пониманий "определения".

Comment: @Alex_ander Я не о том. Я предполагаю, что определение слова амбар начиналось, условно говоря, так: "кладовое помещение для зерна", а одно из определений палаты (тоже условно): "кладовое помещение для драгоценностей". А про "кладовую палату" я почему-то решил, что это типа "зернового амбара" (так тоже говорят), то есть отличает хранилище от хором. Я не спорю, что эта версия надумана. Но она внутренне непротиворечива.

Comment: Палата изначально определялась как "дворец, великолепное **жилое** здание государя и т. п." (Даль), там и "царь Салтан сидел". Едва ли не единственный известный пример "хранения" - оружейная палата, но это лишь частный случай. Под определяющие признаки в старину подводили "каменное (обычно богатое) сооружение (Грановитая п. - с особой отделкой стен)", со сводами, опирающимися на пол и пр. Думаю, всё-таки составители вопроса оплошали, и вполне возможно, что вы вычислили запланированный ими ответ.

Comment: @Alex_ander Здесь не обязательно следовать **изначальному** определению палаты. У того же Даля "сокровищница" -- тоже палата. Но дальше я спорить не буду, мой ответ (даже если он верен) не "щёлкающий", как говорят игроки ЧГК, — с этим согласен.

Comment: Палата, в том числе, — государственное учреждение Древней Руси (Оружейная, Панихидная, Аптекарская, Столовая, упоминаемые с конца XVII в.). В таком смысле я и написал о Кладовой палате.

Comment: @shampar Я понял Ваш первый комментарий, но я думаю, что почти [во всех этих книгах](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=%22%D0%9A%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F+%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%22&dcr=0&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi_pJHXr4LYAhXSZFAKHZhgBZwQ_AUIDygA&biw=1138&bih=523) говорится о чём-то похожем на склад/кладовку.

Comment: Кладовая-верный вариант: В памятниках письменности находим: Н. Никольский "Кирилло-Белозерский монастырь и его устройство";.Спб, Синодальная типография, 1897 г. "...находилась вопервыхъ "келья", затѣмъ "кладовая палата..."; А.А. Титов "Рукописи славянскiя и русскiя", Москва, печатня А. Снегиревой, 1896г. "...кладовой амбаръ, двери на крюках и петляхъ, замокъ нутряной желѣзной, покрытъ соломой...".

Answer (score 0):

Наверное, это слово - холодная. Холодный амбар, холодная палата.

ХОЛОДНАЯ, ой, жен. (устар. прост.). Помещение для арестованных. Посадить в холодную. Толковый словарь Ожегова.

Сначала я подумала, что это столовая. Но Столовая палата есть, а вот были ли столовые амбары, что-то не нашла.Хотя возможно, потому что амбары были и продовольственные, и для мехов. Мне не встречались столовые амбары.

Comment: Хм, интересно, но этот вариант вызывает у меня сомнения: все-таки олимпиада для школьников... навряд ли составители предполагали такое глубокое и редкое знание. По-моему, должно быть что-то более современное и распространенное.

Comment: На таких олимпиадах и более трудные задания есть.

Comment: В воспоминаниях Завалишина (позапрошлый век) упоминается "приёмная палата" (госпиталя); "приёмный амбар" и сейчас иногда встречается - может, "приёмная"?

Comment: "Когда-то" не было приёмного  амбара - приёмного  резервуара для бурового раствора; там был амбар - сарай для зерна или мехов. А он неотапливаемый, т.е. холодный.

Comment: Сто лет, правда, ещё но прошло, но всё-таки: "В 1930 году был сдан в эксплуатацию элеватор на 1500 тонн и приёмный амбар, из которого механизированным способом стали загружать элеватор." (Забелин В.М.  Благодарненские просторы: монография).

Comment: @Aer Что-то знакомое для школьников - "контрольная", можно было бы поискать "контрольный амбар" (вроде контрольного кролика для экспериментов с проращиванием); контрольная палата - дело обычное.